# Captura tecla digitada, utilizando Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Abaixo tenho um código em Python que capturar tecla digitado, só que preciso pegar o nome do programa onde ele digitou tal tecla. Como posso fazer isso?

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging

"""Pega tecla digitada"""

log_dir = "C:/Users/"

logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + "key_log1.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')

def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))
    print(key)
   
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso me cheira coisa de Hackers huahuahua, não sei qual é a intenção disso, espionar ? só saber como funciona ? vou te mostrar como fazer isso e depois você toma as decisões do que é ético ou não ..

Presumo que esteja usando windows, pois vejo um `C:/Users/` em seu código, você vai precisar de alguma lib que consiga trabalhar a nível de `API` do windows, essa `API` tem que comportar as [classes fundamentais da Microsoft](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Classes), óbvio que existe algo assim para Python no windows, vc pode instalar e importar o [win32gui](https://pypi.org/project/win32gui/), dá uma olhada na quantidade de métodos que você consegue pegar do windows com essa lib [aqui](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui.html).

Então vamos lá ver como um hacker do bem faria rsrs, vá na página de documentações da API do windows e procure qual método possui acesso a janela de trabalho atual de um usuário... você irá encontrar o seguinte [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getforegroundwindow) na microsoft, hummm esse tal de `GetForegroundWindow` parece bater com o que vc precisa heimm ?? descrição em inglês da página :

> Retrieves a handle to the foreground window (the window with which the
> user is currently working)

Tradução literal disso ai `Recupera um identificador para a janela do primeiro plano (a janela com a qual o usuário está trabalhando)`

Ok parece ser promissor, mas e ai será que a API do Windows provê alguma função que eu pegue via texto o nome da janela ativa ?

E vamos nós novamente na página da microsoft, olhar a documentação, e mais uma vez bingooo um tal de [GetWindowText](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/-getwindowtext), a descrição me diz:

> Retrieves the text from the specified window's title bar

Ou seja segundo a documentação do Windows está dizendo que recupera o texto da barra de título da janela especificada, então e se usar os dois juntos ? pegar a janela atual em primeiro plano e depois pegar o texto dessa janela que geralmente será o identificador do nome do programa ?? será será ???

Hora da verdade, vamos ver se o que encontramos na página da microsoft foi bem implementado pelo módulo python `win32gui`, procure na documentação do win32gui e vejá se existem esses dois métodos implementados, eu olhei no link da documentação e achei eles lá, então vamos tentar codar e ver se funfa:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow
import logging

"""Pega tecla digitada"""

log_dir = "C:/"

logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + "key_log1.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')

def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))
    print(key)
    print(GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow()))
   
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Olha como ficou `GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow())` e mais uma vez bingooo ... (se eu jogasse bingo pelo menos tava bom kkk)

Teste no chrome

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]